# "User is not eligible for this purchase" - in app billing & publishing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've uploaded my app to the Developer Console, but didn't publish it yet(it's still in draft mode).
Whenever a user who is not a test user tries to use the In App Biiling he receives the following error -

```
User is not eligible for this purchase
```

I've looked around and read some other question regarding the issue, and now I know that the reason for this error is because the user is not a test user and the app hasn't been published.But I still want to be sure of one thing -

**When I publish my application, will the In-App Billing work and users will not receive these errors?**

Thanks!

Comment: Does the user, who received the error, has the old published or a new draft version on his/her device?

Comment: It's a normal behavior then. Normal users are not impacted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to make sure it works like this would be to try it out by yourself.

You can create a new Google Play user account, register it as an alpha/beta tester and release a alpha/beta version of your app (look for ["Testing with real transactions"](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-real) section for more details). It's safe because only your beta tester user can see published application and nobody else. Then install this app to the beta tester's device and check in-app billing works. Then upload a new draft version and make sure beta tester is not impacted.

I had same concern before I published a first version of my application. From today's experience I can say, that normal Google Play users can only see a published version and they do not get any error messages when a new draft is uploaded. Hope this helps.